# Adding a path transistion to pie chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm drawing a pie chart with `d3.js`. I want to transition the pie slices when new data is added. (i'm using the reusable chart API). I'm first creating a chart group using enter and then appending the chart arc path to that:

http://jsfiddle.net/EuK6H/4/

```
var arcGroup = svg.select(".pie").selectAll(".arc " + selector)
                  .data(pie(data))
                  .enter().append("g")
                  .attr("class", "arc " + selector);
                  if (options.left) {
                      arcGroup.attr('transform', 'translate(' + options.left + ',' + options.top + ')');
                  } else {
                      arcGroup.attr('transform', 'translate(' + options.width / 2 + ',' + options.height / 2 + ')');
                  }

//append an arc path to each group
arcGroup.append("path")
        .attr("d", arc)
        //want to add the transition in here somewhere
        .attr("class", function (d) { return 'slice-' + d.data.type; })
        .style("fill", function (d, i) {
            return color(d.data.amount)
        });
       //...
```

Problem is when new data comes in I need to be able to transition the path (and also the text nodes shown in the the fiddle) but the enter selection is made on the the parent group. How can I add a `transition()` so it applies to the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.select()`, which will propagate the data to the selected element. Then you can apply a transition based on the new data. The code would look something like this:

```
var sel = svg.selectAll(".pie").data(pie(newData));

// handle enter + exit selections

// update paths
sel.select("path")
   .transition()
   .attrTween("d", arcTween);
```

Comment: Thanks. This doesn't seem to work as I expected. When I try to remove the paths I get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Array] has no method 'exit" http://jsfiddle.net/EuK6H/13/ Am I not able to remove paths?

Comment: The enter, update and exit selections are available after explicitly binding data with `.data()`, not after subselections. So you would have to do `sliceGroups.exit().select(...).remove()` except that in this case a subselection doesn't really make sense. If you don't remove the entire group, the data matching will be messed up when updating (matching the empty group and not adding anything where you expect something to be added).

Comment: Ah yes I see. Exiting on the subselections wasn't really what I needed. I needed to transition the sub-selections